# Disabling jsonpolling for socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Since jsonpolling messes up my server I would like to disable it.
I found this code on the internet to do so:

```
socket.set('transports', [ 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling' ])
```

I put it into "sockets.on("connection"..." so it looked like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.set('transports', [ 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling' ],function(){
        ....code that I had directly in io.sockets.on("connection"...
    });
});
```

However jsonpolling still seems to be active for it still messes up my server!
What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Right after you import socket.io, can you just do `io.set('transport', [...])`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you initialize socket.io with `listen`, you can specify an object with config options:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80, {
    transports: [...]
});
```

If you need to change it after load time, you can use `io.set('transports', [...])`.

This affects all sockets, so you only need to call it once, not for every socket you create.